# CPU and I/O Burst

Tags: process, cpu, scheduling

Say there are two processes p1 and p2.

Each process has 4 'actions' that follow this format.

CPU Burst - I/O Burst - CPU Burst - I/O Burst.

Say that p2 was currently loaded onto the CPU and is in a CPU Burst state and p1 which was just unloaded is in a I/O Burst state. Will the I/O burst of p1 run at the same time as p2 is running its CPU burst?